# Cannot declare object in jagged array

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

So I'm trying to make an application that calculates the amount of time that you take in one metro transportation , so i make a station class and in the normal form i make a jagged array containing three rows (each row represents a different metro line) so i declare the array like this : `station[][] lines = new station[3][];`and then i declare the rows like this

```
lines[0] = new station[34];
lines[1] = new station[19];
lines[2] = new station[35];
```

and i declare the name and value inside the objects in the jagged array like this:

```
lines[0][0].name = "stationname";
lines[0][0].number = 1;`
```

but when i run the program it gives me a `NullReferenceException`,
I know that i didn't declare the objects right(i think) and I don't know how to declare them right.
Well, here's a more complete code sample :

```
        station[][] lines = new station[3][];
        lines[0] = new station[34];
        lines[0][0] = new station {name = "حلوان", number = 1 };
        lines[0][0].number = 1;
        lines[0][1].name = "عين حلوان";
        lines[0][1].number = 2;
        lines[0][2].name = "جامعة حلوان";
        lines[0][2].number = 3;
        lines[0][3].name = "وادى حوف";
        lines[0][3].number = 4;
        lines[0][4].name = "حدائق حلوان";
        lines[0][4].number = 5;
```

Row Two

```
            lines[1] = new station[19];
        lines[1][0].name = "المنيب";
        lines[1][0].number = 36;
        lines[1][1].name = "ساقية مكى";
        lines[1][1].number = 37;
        lines[1][2].name = "ضواحى الجيزة";
        lines[1][2].number = 38;
        lines[1][3].name = "محطة الجيزة";
        lines[1][3].number = 39;
        lines[1][4].name = "فيصل";
        lines[1][4].number = 40;
        lines[1][5].name = "جامعة القاهرة";
        lines[1][5].number = 41;
```

Row 3

```
            lines[2] = new station[35];
        lines[2][0].name = "مطار القاهرة";
        lines[2][0].number =54;
        lines[2][1].name = "السلام";
        lines[2][1].number = 55;
        lines[2][2].name = "عمر بن الخطاب";
        lines[2][2].number = 56;
        lines[2][3].name = "قباء";
        lines[2][3].number = 57;
        lines[2][4].name = "النزهة٢";
        lines[2][4].number = 58;
        lines[2][5].name = "النزهة١";
        lines[2][5].number = 59;
```

Comment: Can you post the actual code. Also show which line the error is on.

Comment: When you declare a jagged array, you first declare all the dimensions as a new array, but then you have to iterate along, say, the first dimension and declare a new array of length X for each array in that dimension.  Bear in mind a jagged array is an array of arrays.  So you "new" the array of arrays, then "new" each array in it.

Comment: Oh but if lines[0][0].name is referring to a Class or Struct with a property named .Name, then you have to initialize that Class or Struct also.  This is usually done by the constructor, so . . . yeah, please post a bit more code so we can see what is happening there.

Comment: Actually the error happens when I start the program but then it gives a NullReferenceException right at the start when I'm declaring the Name and the number , I get it now , I should have made "New" first and then declare the name and the number , though i have more than a hundred lines of wrong code , if someone knows how can i edit them all quick please tell me , my whole group is working on this program and I'm slowing them down :(

Comment: Visual Studio has excellent find and replace capability.  Even Regex matching (which I do not understand).  But if for example you can highlight "line [" in that top block of code and replace it with "new line [" it may work.  Without seeing the specific code I cannot be sure.

Comment: @WDS I posted Specific code and i will post the other rows right now , just so i can finish it quickly , and thank you :)

Comment: Looking forward to the other code.  It almost looks like you are trying to use a Class (undefined even) and the second dimension of the array for the same purpose.  Yes, the more code you post the easier it is to see what is happening there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You initialized the arrays well but you didn't initialize any object inside them.

Do:

```
lines[0][0] = new Station() { name = "...", number = 1 };
```

PS: I suppose you mean `Station` not `station` right?

Comment: station is a class I made containing a string called name and a value called number , its name is all in small letters. :)

Comment: @GamerGamesGames didn't know C# allows class names to start in lowercase. Anyway your classes should start with a capital letter.

Comment: @MihaiBratulescu its allowed. But it sure isnt typical.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is maybe a little confusion.  I tried to capture what I think your meaning is.  That you want an array of lines and that within that array, each line contains an array of Stations.  And each Station has a name and number.  Based on this understanding, here is some code that will work and gives an idea how the rest of it should be structured.

```
    internal class Station
    {
        internal string name;
        internal int stationNumber;
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Station[][] line = new Station[3][]; // Assuming 3 lines total

        line[0] = new Station[34]; // This is saying line #0 (stored in element major 0) needs 34 elements, each of which will contain a Station instance
        line [0][0] = new Station { "حلوان", 1 };
        line [0][1] = new Station {"عين حلوان", 2};
        line[0][2] = new Station {"جامعة حلوان",3};
        line[0][3] = new Station {"وادى حوف",4};
        line[0][4] = new Station { "حدائق حلوان", 5 };
    }
```

Comment: I hope this makes sense.  It can be quite difficult to know what you need without seeing the whole program, but I hope this gives you a good idea what you need to do to prevent the error you were getting.

Comment: exactly :) , why i used the jagged array is because there are different numbers of stations in each line , though there are stations which are the same but are in two different lines , for those i just make EX: `line[1][6] = helwan //(already declared object)`

Comment: Hmm, that is weird.  I made the code in VS2013, but when I copy / pasted here, it moved the quotes.  Probably the software having trouble with the right-to-left alphabet.  Anyway I am sure you know what I wanted to post, that the quotes go around the string and not around the number as it is here.

Comment: yes , but then it would be EX : `line[0][0] = new Station {name = "Station Name",number = (value)}` :) because just a number would give an error :)

Comment: Yes, sort of.  Inside the brackets, though, you give the values in order they appear in the Class definition, but you do not need to provide the "name =" part.  You can, but you don't have to do so.

Comment: so for example:  line[0][0] = new Station {"Station Name" , value} will also work.

Comment: Oh. well that's new , thanks for the new knowledge :D